# Need Best Jquery DatePicker Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need a jQuery date picker. I am doing web devlopment and in the project I have to use date picker in a different way and at different part of the page.
Can anyone provide a link to download the date picker?

Comment: No one's going to email anything to you. That's not how Stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Ya ya its a Good date picker.Thanks for you atttention budy

Answer (score -1):

**[Air Datepicker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/)** is the **BEST** and the **COOLEST**. it's my favorite